# Django ModelForm with foreign key: form.is_vaild=False when empty value selected

Tags: django, modelform

I have just one field with null=True in my model:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=None)
```

and simplest form:

```
class DistrictForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ['district']
```

and my view.py:

```
def district_details(request, district_id):
    district = get_object_or_404(TestModel, pk=district_id)

    context = {}
    context['district'] = district
    context['frmDistrict'] = DistrictForm(instance=district)
    context['form_title'] = u'{} (id {})'.format(district, district.id)
    return render(request, "editor/district_details.html", context)

def district_update(request, district_id):
    district = get_object_or_404(TestModel, pk=district_id)
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        form = DistrictForm(data=request.POST, instance=district)
        if form.is_valid():
            district.save()
            messages.success(request, u'District «{}» successfully updated.'.format(district))
            return redirect('editor:district_details', district_id=district.id)
        else:
            messages.warning(request, u"District is not updated. Please correct mistakes in the form." + unicode(form.is_bound))
    else:
        form = DistrictForm(instance=district)
    return district_details(request, district_id=district_id)
```

and template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>
{% for message in messages %}{{ message }}{% endfor %}
{{ form_title }}

<form id="frmSeries" action="{% url 'editor:district_update' district_id=district.id %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ frmDistrict }}
<input type="submit" name="frmDistrict_submit" value="Сохранить" />
</form>
{% include 'results/panel_footer.html' %}
{{ frmDistrict.errors }}
{{ frmDistrict.non_field_errors }}
{{ request.POST }}
  </body>
</html>
```

It works fine when I change the district, but the problem is when I select empty value in my form.
form_is_valid() is False, but both frmDistrict.errors and frmDistrict.non_field_errors are empty! And form.is_bound() is True.

And when I add a field to my form, I get another problem. After modifying ModelForm this way:

```
class DistrictForm(ModelForm):
    district = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=District.objects.order_by('name'),
        empty_label="empty",
        required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ['district']
```

when I select "empty" in the dropdown, form submits successfully, but the value of "district" field just doesn't change!

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you expecting anything called `frmDistrict` to work? Your form is just called `form`.

Comment: And if you want a to be valid with no value, you need to set `blank=False` as well as `null=False`.

Comment: The form is sometimes called `form`, sometimes `frmDistrict`, that's OK.
And `blank=False` helped, thank you very much!
But why isn't `null=True` enough...